# Play Framework 2.4.1: How to remove an element from a JsArray

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

Given the following JSON...

```
scala>  val js = Json.parse("""{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2","list":[{"item1": "value1"},{"item2": "value2"}]}""")
js: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","list":[{"item1":"value1"},{"item2":"value2"}]}
```

... I get the first element of `list` like this:

```
scala> val l = (js \ "list").as[List[JsValue]]
l: List[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = List({"item1":"value1"}, {"item2":"value2"})

scala> val first = l(0)
first: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"item1":"value1"}
```

... but how do I remove an element from `list` at a given index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in `JsValue` nor `JsPath` for this, you could use a Lens library such as [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle).  Otherwise, here's one way of doing that:

```
(js \ "list").get match {
  case JsArray(items) => dropAt(items, 1)
}
```

where `dropAt` is:

```
def dropAt[A](items: Seq[A], id: Int): Seq[A] =
  items.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 != id).map(_._1)
```

(`dropAt` is not pretty but I'm not aware of any nice API for that.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `dropAt` in the standard collections library.  You can add one using the enrich-my-library pattern.  When enriching collections, you're often best off using the `CanBuildFrom` structure, which will allow you to keep strong types.  You might implement `dropAt` as:

```
implicit class TraversableDropAt[A, Repr <: Traversable[A]](val xs: TraversableLike[A, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
  def dropAt[That](n: Int)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, That]): That = {
    val bf = cbf()
    bf.sizeHint(xs.size - 1) 
    bf ++= xs.take(n)
    bf ++= xs.drop(n + 1)
    bf.result
  }
}
```

This will allow you to call `myCollection.dropAt(n)` for any `Traversable` extension (e.g. `List`, `Seq`, `Iterable`, etc.).

When you're working with the PlayJSON types, you're often best off converting them to normal Scala types as soon as possible.  Here, you can turn the array to a `Seq[JsValue]` in several ways:

```
val items = (js \ "list").as[Seq[JsValue]]
val items = (js \ "list").as[JsArray].value
val items = (js \ "list") match { case JsArray(items) => items }
val JsArray(items) = (js \ "list")
```

Once you have the `items` collection, you can use the new `dropAt` method on it.

Another option would be to add the `dropAt` method directly to `JsArray` (or even `JsValue`) using the enrich-my-library pattern shown above.

If you need to convert back to a `JsArray`, you can use the `Json.arr` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove elements by converting it to a mutable collection rather than the immutable list. On mutable collection, you can call the `remove(int: Index)` operation that will modify the collection. So your case could be written as

```
val js = Json.parse("""{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2","list":[{"item1": "value1"},{"item2": "value2"}]}""")
val l = (js \ "list").as[ArrayBuffer[JsValue]]

l.remove(0) // returns the removed element at index 0 but modifies the underlying collection l
```